# Query analyzer for Sybase

Tags: c#, sql, sybase, analyzer

I'm querying Sybase database from C# code. Is there any good query analyzer to understand the exact queries being generated like the Query Analyzer for Sql Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some Sybase variables to see the Query Plan such as the following:

```
set showplan  on
set statistics io on
set statistics time on
exec my_proc (my_arg1, my_arg2, ...)
go
```

I have put this into a shell script to pass the command line arguments.  In that case these SQL lines are preceded with the following:

```
isql  -Uxxx   -Pyyy   <<-_EOF_
```

And the exec line becomes:

```
exec $*
```

And the script ends with:

```
go
_EOF_
```

Good SQL, good night.

kelley805